# PHP - split xyz ammount of images from gallery into hyperlinks

Tags: php, image, split

I have a rather hard time figuring out a specific way to split large ammounts of images into hyperlinks. I don`t know how to explain it well, but here is a example what I mean:

"In the pastebin below because I can`t post more than 2 links, marked #A"

On this site, go to "Dias" then hit the button "anzeigen" right of Afrika, in the left 8000 images are split into hyperlinks, always 100 showing at once.

I have to make the way exactly like this, but with a different gallery. Here is the link to the page I`m currently working on:

"In the pastebin below because I can`t post more than 2 links, makred #B"

The same as above, on Dias you will see the gallery and on the left side it should also split them up into hyperlinks.

I pasted the code on pastebin because it`s long:
http://pastebin.com/LYbYFcug
On line 1. it begins with the .php that makes the gallery on the right frame and on line 126. it starts with the .php which shows the pictures.

I hope you can help me, already stuck since a week on this....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it with array_chunk and the input form:

```
$chunk = array_chunk($filecounter, 100);

$minval = 1;

if($num < 100 ){
    $maxval = $num;
}else{
    $maxval = 100;
}

$output = "";



foreach ($chunk as $k){


?>


<form action="***.php" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php foreach($filename as $n => $name){echo $name . " ";} ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="imagelink[]" value="<?php print_r( $img_file) ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="imagethumb[]" value="<?php print_r ($img_folder) ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php print_r(count($k)); ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="serie" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="minval" value="<?php print_r($minval) ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="maxval" value="<?php print_r($maxval) ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value=" <?php  echo $minval." - ".$maxval;  ?>"/>
</form>

<?php
$minval = $minval + 100;
$maxval = $maxval + 100;

}
?>
```